# DHCP Client Discover packet

Tags: dhcp, raw-sockets

Using Windows 7 PC and single Network Card with DHCP Server in the network. PC already have configured interface.

So im trying to send(with help of winpcap raw sockets) DHCP DISCOVER message with OTHER MAC from this Network card, for testing purpose. Of course send as broadcast, with DHCP Message type option. But DHCP Server dont answer this (Wireshark dont show anything but discover packet).

So my question: Is problem with server\client side, or dhcp server will not take request from already configured network card(i have no idea how it knows about it)?

Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

release the current address first then send the dhcp discover, or generate a dhcp discover message